# New Added Types in .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1

Tags: .net, .net-2.0

I assumed there were only bug fixes/(no new types) in .NET 2.0 SP1 until I came across [few](http://davesbox.com/archive/2008/08/25/new-for-visual-studio-2008-sp1-and-fxcop-1-36-multi-targeting-rule.aspx) posts which were mentioning [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) structure, that was added in .NET 2.0 SP1.

Is there a full listing of the newly added types in .NET 2.0 SP1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

[image]

Full Article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CatchingRedBitsDifferencesInNET20AndNET20SP1.aspx

This may also be helpful:

[image]

Full Article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangesInTheNETBCLBetween20And35.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There were new interfaces added, like INotifyPropertyChanging, so there were new types added. The question is valid.

Answer (score 0):

DateTimeOffset was added to 2.0 SP1 - I'm not aware of any other new types.

Given the coincidental timing, it's perhaps worth reminding people that 2.0 SP1 shipped with 3.5 RTM (i.e November 2007) and 2.0 SP2 shipped with 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what D2VIANT referenced

> Full Article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CatchingRedBitsDifferencesInNET20AndNET20SP1.aspx

I was able to find additional resources which list the changes in .NET SP1 some of the types added/affected are listed below

- System.DateTimeOffset
- System.GCCollectionMode
- System.Runtime.GCLatencyMode
- System.Configuration.OverrideMode
- System.Data.SqlClient.SortOrder
- System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetSchemaImporterExtensionFx35
- System.Data.TypedDataSetGenerator.GenerateOption
- System.UriIdnScope
- System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging
- System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangingEventArgs
- System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangingEventHandler
- System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerLoaderHost2
- System.Configuration.IdnElement
- System.Configuration.IriParsingElement
- System.Configuration.UriSection
- System.Net.Sockets.SendPacketsElement
- and Many More...  [API Changes from org2.0 to 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/org2.0to2.0/APIChangesorg2.0to2.0.html) and [New Methods and Types](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/RedBitsChangesv2.html)